# Count how many divs has a specific content?

Tags: jquery

I want to count how many divs with the class `.tool` that contain the following html by example : `<b>Photoshop</b>`

```
<div class="tool"><b>After Effects</b></div>
<div class="tool"><b>Photoshop</b></div>
<div class="tool"><b>Illustrator</b></div>
<div class="tool"><b>Photoshop</b></div>
<div class="tool"><b>Photoshop</b></div>
// This would return 3
```

How to do that using jQuery? i only can count all `.tool` divs?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var count = $(".tool").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Photoshop';
}).length;
```

If you insist on matching the HTML:

```
var count = $(".tool").filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() == '<b>Photoshop</b>';
}).length;
```

Comment: `$.map` will return an object with the same length as the *all the matched elements*, I think you want to use [`$.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: @CMS - you are right, I stand corrected. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

or use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("div.tool:contains('Photoshop')").length
```

Comment: That would also match 'Photoshop Plugins', 'Photoshop Tutorials' etc. That said, it might do for the OP's problem.